# Creating a database of numbers in Python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python so I just need a bit of guidance.

I'm reading from a database using a custom function by calling a particular address (an int). The function will return me another int and then I want to convert the returned integer to a hex. The problem is that the function will ONLY return me the int and nothing else.

My question is this: How do I make a dictionary type object that I can access the outputted decimal AND the hex value from the int address I used to get them in the first place.

I also want to be able to print it out in a legible way.

Wonder if anyone can give me some guidance.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the question. Also this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; if your question is *how do I convert an integer to hex in Python* that seems trivially Googlable. If not, please clarify what it is, ideally with a [mcve] of your current implementation. See [ask].

Comment: What do you mean by calling an address? In general, you do not deal with addresses in Python. Also, what do you mean by "convert an int to a hex". A `hex` isn't a data type.

Comment: I know how to convert integers to a hex format. Yes I understand it's not a data type, I understand that if I use "hex" it will output a type string. I don't care what class it is in, I just want to be able to output and see the hex representation of the int.

Comment: What I mean by address is that the function takes a integer input (which happens to be an address in the device I'm connected to). Basically I want to be able to see the decimal and hex equivalent output corresponding to the integer I put into the function. Finally, I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me. I'm simply looking for some guidance into the logic on how I could do it on Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store, you can use the Python built-in dictionary type (`dict`)

Say your function to get the integer values is `f`. Then, you can store each address's return value:

```
returned_ints = {}
for address in addresses:
    returned_ints[address] = f(address)
```

I would suggest against storing the hexadecimal value, as this can be easily computed using the `hex` function when you need it. However, if you are adamant about storing it, you can store both the return value and the hexadecimal representation as a tuple:

```
ret = f(address)
returned_ints[address] = (ret, hex(ret))
```

Then, to get the value for any specific address, you would use `returned_ints[address][0]`; similarly, you can get the hexadecimal representation using `returned_ints[address][1]`.

Comment: Please don't mind my ignorance, but is there any reason why storing the hex value is a bad practice? I'm not doubting you, I'm just curious why. But thanks for this answer! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @jgv115 It's not the best practice because you can easily get the hex value using the `hex` function, which is quick to do. Unless you require the hex representation many times, it's just as easy to call the `hex` function when you need it as opposed to looking up a pre-computed value.